# emulate spacebar scroll function

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a function which scrolls to every image, but when in text i'd like to emulate the spacebar function

So the code I have is:

```
window.scrollBy(0,window.innerHeight*0.8);
```

but I'd like to be more accurate so does anyone knows the native code of the space bar scroll function?

Comment: Well it's exactly 0.875. made a test. But that make me ask another question? How to know native functions?

Comment: Not exactly 0.875 it depends on the browser
http://nerd.vasilis.nl/high-scroll-height-scrolling-space-bar/

Answer (score 0):

`window.scrollTo` will do that. You'll have to use the current scroll position + a set interval like

`window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY+=200)`

I'm not sure what interval the space bar actually uses but I'm sure you can find a value you're happy with.

edit: window.pageYOffset might be more browser friendly. Here's the space bar emulated in your own code. Not sure why you'd want to:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) { 
    if(event.keyCode===32){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset+=window.innerHeight*0.8)
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think it's around 0.8 size of the window height

Comment: that would make it `window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY+=window.innerHeight*0.8)`