# Where can i find the code "behind the hood" of JS array methods?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how array methods are built-in (the source code), for example this prototype todos() is how i imagine the every() method works behind the scenes, i would like to find that documentation.

```js
Array.prototype.todos = function(fn) {
    for(let item of this) {
        if(!fn(item)) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

const result = [1, 2, 3].todos(x => x < 10)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: There is no universal implementation. Chromium + v8 has its own implementation in c++, Bun has its own implementation through JavaScriptCore, etc

Comment: Which javascript engine? V8? JavascriptCore? SpiderMonkey? You may imagine that "every" works like that, but the implementation is probably not written in javascript

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371251/how-to-get-native-javascript-functions-source-code

Comment: All the javascript engines are open source (yes, even Microsoft's old Chakra engine). You are free to download and read them. This is actually a good exercise on how to read complex codebases. Download all of them (or just browse them in github) and try to find the implementation of the array methods

Answer (score 2):

The contract for exactly how the Javascript built-ins should behave is outlined in the **[ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.every)**.

There are a number of different Javascript engines, each with their own specific implementation of ECMAScript. The most common Javascript engines are:

- [**V8** (Chrome, Node, Edge, Android, Opera, other Chromium-based browsers)](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/5d011e66394cc6775488b62e1f9b925ef38c2333/src/builtins/array-every.tq)
- [**SpiderMonkey** (Firefox)](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/48f5edbe59bf79841a34129797197b1e6c32242b/js/src/builtin/Array.js#L6-L35)
- [**JavaScriptCore** (Safari)](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/e1a91728aa9546490b69cc41f68aef017b49d760/Source/JavaScriptCore/builtins/ArrayPrototype.js#L93-L113)

Comment: gecko and webkit are not javascript engines - did you mean SpiderMonkey and JavaScriptCore? or did you mean Blink instead of V8?